# OpenCV - NoneType not subscriptable

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, nonetype

I'm not understanding why my code is throwing a *'NoneType' object is not subscriptable* error as I run this:

```
y = []
for every_img in sorted(os.listdir(easyocr_test)):
    img = cv2.imread(easyocr_test + "/" + every_img)
    left_image = img[13:40, 570:606]
    y.append(left_image)
```

I want `y` to append a specific area of all images within the `easyocr_test` folder. Why does it not let me do this? I'm puzzled.

I've tried recreating a VENV but to no avail.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/python_projects/test10/test1.py", line 12, in <module>
    left_image = img[13:40, 570:606]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: The error means the `img` variable is None, probably because can not read the image file.  Try to put the entire path `easyocr_test + "/" + every_img` in a variable and print it, probably the error is there

Comment: You should check that the images actually exist. Better to use `pathlib` or `glob` to work with file paths.

Comment: when `cv2` can't read some file then it doesn't raise error but it returns `None` and later this makes problem. It may need `if img is no None:` or you have to check file extension and open only images

Answer (score 1):

To avoid iterating over unwanted files, I suggest using a [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) pattern and `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path(easyocr_test)       # Path to the folder containing the imgs
img_paths = folder.glob('*.png')  # or e.g. '*.jpg', adjust accordingly

y = []
for img_path in sorted(img_paths):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    left_image = img[13:40, 570:606]
    y.append(left_image)
```